# How to show/hide an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a div element to test hiding and showing an element in JS for my calendar program. I have a function that uses `x.style.display` to render or hide the div, "info", in the page. But it doesn't work when I test it; when I click the button the "info" div stays on the screen as normal.

```js
function show() {
  var divide = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;
  if (divide.style.display === "hidden") {
    divide.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    divide.style.display = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Show/Hide</button>
<div class="info">Testy</div>
```

Comment: put `<script type = "text/javascript" src = "div.js"></script>` at the end of the `body`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? And how is this related to PHP?

Comment: `document.getElementById("info")` What element has this **ID**?

Comment: Remove **.innerHtml** because you are setting divide to the HTML (text string) instead of the DOM Node. The DOM node has the style property, strings do not.

Comment: You have `var divide = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;` but your `div` uses a `class`. Current: `var divide = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;`What it should be:
`var divide = document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerHTML;`
Your `<div>`: `<div class="info">Testy</div>`

Comment: That question does not answer this person's question. This person has a syntax error.

Comment: remove innerHTML, change class to id on div and change hidden with none and it works

Answer (score 3):

You have used innerHtml is use to assign string. So remove that and hide you can use `display:none` not hidden.

```js
function show() {
  var divide = document.getElementById("info");
  if (divide.style.display === "none") {
    divide.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    divide.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="info">Testy</div>
<button onclick="show()">Show/Hide</button>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and don't simply say "Go through this answer"

Comment: when the original element has display: none, it will have to click twice to display it